# Tower of Hanoi using Head Recursion?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was wondering if the standard Tower of Hanoi problem can be solved using head recursion. I have a vague idea that it should not be possible with the same numbering of discs (from 1 (smallest) to N (largest) disc) and 3 towers.

Answer (score 0):

For most sensible versions of what you could mean, no.  Technically the answer is yes.

The whole point of the Towers of Hanoi problem is that an apparently simple problem needs two recursive calls.  Which immediately implies that it cannot be naturally solved with either tail recursion or head recursion.

However the solution can be completely analyzed and solved in an iterative algorithm.  We can examine a position, calculate where we must be in the solution, and produce the next answer.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-tower-of-hanoi/ for an example of this analysis.

And what can be written using a single iterative loop can always be rewritten from there using either tail recursion or head recursion.  You get tail recursion by doing one iteration then making a recursive call to continue in the loop.  You get head recursion by first doing the recursive call to get to the currently desired position, and then doing the current iteration.

So yes, with much effort you can get head recursion with its attendant horrible memory and performance characteristics.